# Remove Sample Reports from pentaho community edition

Tags: pentaho

Can anyone help me with how to remove the sample documents eg.Steelwheel etc. from pentaho community edition. I found a resource [here](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/topic/install_ziptar/task_remove_sample_data.html) but when I do it, it causes the bi server to crash. So am not sure if its the right thing to do. Has anyone achieved this successfully, help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting the sample folders in the Solution Repository should be enough.

You should also delete the SampleData and SteelWheels data sources using the Data Source Manager.

Comment: Yeah, I figured that one out a while after. Thanks though. I will accept your answer.